# C++ how to replace text that has been output?

Tags: c++14

I am trying to make a loading screen, with a circle made of these characters: / - | \
so it will output like this:

```
|

/

-

\

|

/

-

\
```

but instead of just outputting it, I was wondering how I would replace the previous character in a timed interval. thank you!

Comment: What have you actually tried? And why didn't it work?

Comment: I haven't tried anything... I am new to programming, so I have no clue where to start

Comment: Generally people won't help you on here unless you show what you have tried and why it didn't work. Some going so far as to down vote your question if you're just asking someone else to solve it for you. I'll see what I can do for you though.

Comment: The answer is a bit trickier than I expected. It seems you have two options. The easiest solution would be using \r which will return the cursor to the start of the line and then you can overwrite the output each time your print. Otherwise you can use ncurses which might be a bit overkill for this question. I'll have another look when I'm no longer at work if you haven't figured it out by then. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way to do this is to use `\r`. That would only work for a single line though.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::literals;

int main() {
  static const std::string sequence = "|/-\\";
  auto duration = 5s;
  auto duration_step = 250ms;
  for (auto i = 0; i < (duration/duration_step); ++i) {
    std::cout << "\r" << sequence[i%sequence.size()] << std::flush;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(duration_step);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

More advanced behaviors require a library (such as `ncurses`) and more work, especially for a beginner.